# xpath: count elements in XML document

Tags: xpath

I have a fairly large XML document. The basic structure of that XML is as follows:

```
<document>
    <title>
        Title
    </title>
    <frontm>
        <toc>
        </toc>
    </frontm>
    <body>
        <section>
            <section>
                <p>content</p>
            </section>
        </section>
        <section>
            <section>
                <p>content</p>
            </section>
        </section>
        <section>
            <section>
                <p>content</p>
            </section>
        </section>
        <section>
            <section>
                <p>content</p>
            </section>
        </section>
    </body>
</document>
```

I have tried the following xpath but it returns just half the number of sections:

```
count(../../body/section/section/following-sibling::node())+1
```

Any ideas?

Edit: I am trying to count the number of sections in sections (applied to the example above, the xpath should return 4).

Comment: What exactly are you trying to count?  All the elements, all the `section` elements, just the `section` elements that are not nested inside another `section`, or something else.  To put it another way, what answer do you want to get given the example XML you've provided?

Comment: Your XPath expression is a *relative* expression. It makes no sense at all if you don't inform in which context it should be considered (what is the current node)? Can you express it as an absolute expression (starting in /)?

Comment: Sorry im not that clear about what i was trying to achieve (english is not my native toungh). I have added a better explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to count the `section` elements

If you want to count the leaf node sections without making assumptions about `p` children

```
count(//section[ancestor::section])
```

Similarly, if you want to count the parent sections

```
count(//section[section])
```

And if you want to count *all* section elements, at any level:

```
count(//section)
```